# "Are you a human?" frequency hugely increased

Tags: bug, captcha, robots

I see there are similar questions from 2012, but cannot find something more recent.

The frequency of "Are you a human" checks has become excessive recently - I get them on the majority of searches I make. Most of the time I am not logged in, but my device and IP are not predictable.

I suspect that the cause is most of the time that I am making a search on a stack exchange site using the search function itself I am looking for a list of interesting looking discussions. So for instance, I will search for "bug compatibility" to see if there are any interesting looking tales of what folk have had to implement over the years.

I can see how this can look a lot like a bot. But surely I'm not the only person who uses stack exchange sites like this?

Comment: As the answer there say, searches from non-logged-in users require this check in general, this is not specific to your device or location. As a workaround, you can use google search with `site:something.stackexchange.com` parameter. It usually gives better results anyway.

Comment: @1999 It's ip-based however and the check is required only for the first time. Not sure it's time-relative.

Comment: @nicael - If it's supposed to be required only the first time, then that feature is broken OR relies on some sort of finger printing technique that ghostery interferes with

Comment: Just made a new [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259611/dont-ask-for-human-verification-when-im-already-logged-in-to-another-stack-s) from my answer here

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

This is additionally frustrating when one is already logged in to another Stack site (usually various sites).

As our profile is networked, it would be really good if the scripts that ask if we're a robot instead identified when we are logged in to another site.

Not necessarily auto-log us in at this point, as we'd not asked to be, but at least if I'm logged in to another Stack network site don't ask me if I'm a bot :)